# Constant autocovariance

Tags: autocorrelation

I was wondering what does a process $X_t$ with constant autocovariance $\gamma(h)\equiv c$ look like ? Is there something interesting to note about it ?

A particular case of this process is $X_t \equiv c$, in fact its auto covariance is given by $\gamma(h)=0.$ This case is of course not very exciting.

Comment: This is equivalent to stating all the $X_t$ are perfectly correlated with each other with common covariance, whence any $X_t$ and $X_s$ must differ by a constant.  Would you perhaps be trying to ask about the more interesting situation where $\gamma(0)=1$ but $\gamma(h)=c$ for $h\ne 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the process has constant 0 mean (otherwise consider the process $\{X_t - E[X_t]\}$ instead). The constant autocovariance condition then necessarily requires $X_t \equiv X$ for some random variable $X$ with $E[X^2] < \infty$, for all $t \in \mathcal{T}$.

Fix $t_0 \in \mathcal{T}$. For any $t \neq t_0$ and $t \in \mathcal{T}$. By $\gamma(t - t_0) = \gamma(0) = c \geq 0$, it can be seen that the equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\operatorname{Cov}(X_t, X_{t_0}) = \gamma(t - t_0) \leq \gamma(0)$ holds. Hence there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $X_t = \lambda X_{t_0}$. Taking variances on both sides of this equality then yields $c = \lambda^2c$. If $c = 0$, then $X_t = 0$ almost surely for all $t \in \mathcal{T}$ (the case you mentioned).  If $c > 0$, then $\lambda = \pm 1$. But $\lambda = -1$ is impossible, otherwise $\operatorname{Cov}(X_t, X_{t_0}) = \operatorname{Cov}(-X_{t_0}, X_{t_0}) = -\gamma(0) = -c \neq c$. This shows that $X_t = X_{t_0}$.